# Condition for the generic fiber to be dense

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

This is an assertion in the article *Groupes Reductifs sur un Corps Locale II* by Bruhat and Tits.  Here $A$ is an integral domain with field of fractions $K$, and $\mathfrak X$ is an *affine* $A$-scheme with coordinate ring $B := A[\mathfrak X]$.

[image]

I don't think this assertion that density is equivalent to torsion free is true in the generality they state.  I can show $\Rightarrow$ if $B$ is reduced.

Density means that for any $b\in B$ which is not in the nilradical of $B$, there exists a prime $\mathfrak p$ of $B$ such that $b \not\in \mathfrak p$ and $\phi^{-1}\mathfrak p = (0)$.

Scratchwork: Assume $B$ is reduced.  For the implication $\Rightarrow$, assume $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ are both not zero.  We need to show that $\phi(a) b \neq 0$.   Then $b$ is not nilpotent, which means the open set $D(b)$ is nonempty.  By density, there exists a prime $\mathfrak p$ of $B$ such that $b \not\in \mathfrak p$ and $\phi^{-1}\mathfrak p = (0)$.  Since $\phi(a)$ and $b$ each do not lie in $\mathfrak p$, neither does $\phi(a)b$, so $\phi(a)b \neq 0$.

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is a standard result: an injective ring homomorphism makes for a dominant morphism of schemes.

Comment: Could you please translate the question for English readers?

Comment: "Let $\mathfrak X$ be an $A$-scheme.  In order that the generic fiber $\mathfrak X_K$ be dense in $\mathfrak X$, it is necessary and sufficient that $\mathfrak X$ be "torsion free," which is to say that the $A$-module $A[\mathfrak X]$ is torsion free: each of these conditions means that the canonical map $j_{\mathfrak X}: A[\mathfrak X] \rightarrow K[\mathfrak X]$ is injective.  We will then identify $A[\mathfrak X]$ and its image in $K[\mathfrak X]$.  This applies in particular if $\mathfrak X$ is flat, which is to say if the $A$-module $A[\mathfrak X]$ is flat."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: this result is not true without assuming $B$ is reduced.  For a simple example, take $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $B=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2,2x)$.  Then $A$ is $B$ mod its nilradical, so the map $\operatorname{Spec} B\to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is a homeomorphism and so the generic fiber is dense in $\operatorname{Spec} B$ since the generic point is dense in $\operatorname{Spec} A$.  But $B$ is not torsion-free: as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/(2)$.